# How do I evaluate this integral by parts?

Tags: calculus, integration, indefinite-integrals

So before anyone asks yes this is a homework question but my professor has allowed us to use the internet for help. Anyways my professor would like us to evaluate this integral by parts.
$$
\int t \sec^2 dt
$$

Although when I tried it I got this. [image: My work]. This seems to easy to me and I feel that I am doing something wrong and I was hoping someone could explain to me what that is.

Comment: $\int\tan t\ dt=-\ln\cos t+C$.

Comment: Oh wow I just didn't know my anti-derivatives as well as I thought. Should I delete this question?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given $\int t\sec^2(t)\ dt$

By integration by parts $u=t, v^{\prime}=\sec^2t$

$$=t\tan(t)-\int\tan(t)\ dt$$$$=t\tan(t)+\ln|\cos(t)|+C$$